# Issue in cygwin saying cannot run the configured compiler 'C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe'

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I tried installing PERL module via cygwin. It is giving following error

```
bash-3.2$ perl Makefile.PL
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)
Now let's see what we can find out about your system
(logfiles of failing tests are available in the conf/ dir)...

ERROR: cannot run the configured compiler 'C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe'
(see conf/compilerok.log). Suggestions:
1) The complier 'C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe' is not in your PATH. Add it
   to the PATH and try again. OR
2) The compiler isn't installed on your system. Install it. OR
3) You only have a different compiler installed (e.g. 'gcc').
   Either fix the compiler config in the perl Config.pm
   or install a perl that was built with the right compiler
   (you could build perl yourself with the available compiler).

Note: this is a system-administration issue, please ask your local
admin for help. Thank you.
```

I checked and found that gcc.exe is installed in C:\cygwin\bin

Any clues?

Comment: Sure, try updating more than once a decade.  `bash-3.2` and `gcc-3.4.4` are ancient and have not been supported for years.

Comment: @Yaakov: which one is latest version then

Comment: http://cygwin.com/packages/